# Using cv2 dnn with .model filetype?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, keras

I've been following [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/08/21/deep-learning-with-opencv/) tutorial and wanted to import a TensorFlow/keras model using "cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorFlow" However, I only have .model files for my premade models, but I think I need .pb? Do you know how to get around this? Thanks!

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, OpenCV is [not compatible yet with SavedModel](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16582) but in the link to the issue you can find code how to convert your savedModel to protobuf so it can be loaded with OpenCV